# "What do you like about your home country" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would you translate "What do you like about your home country"?

> Was mögen Sie über deinem Heimatland?
>   Was hatten Sie von Ihrem Heimatland gefallen?

If you have something better, please put that in. Please explain why or why not one is better or worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get good translations if you correct your errors.

I beginn with the first sentence:

> Was mögen Sie über deinem Heimatland?

**first error:**

The preposition »über« doesn't fit to the verb »mögen«. In German you don't combine *mögen* with *über* but with *an*:

This is better, but still not good:

> Was mögen Sie **an** deinem Heimatland?

**second error:**

Du not mix »du« and »Sie« within a sentence when talking to the same person.

Either you use »du«, then you get this:

> Was **magst du** an deinem Heimatland?

Or you use »Sie«:

> Was mögen Sie an **Ihrem** Heimatland?

Both versions are ok.

---

Let's step to your second sentence

> Was hatten Sie <del>von</del> Ihrem Heimatland gefallen?

**third error:**

Again the wrong preposition. »Von« does not fit to »gefallen«. Again it must be »an«:

Little bit better, but still wrong:

> Was hatten Sie **an** Ihrem Heimatland gefallen?

**fourth error:**

The person you are talking to is in the wrong case. It must not be nominative (»Sie«) but accusative (»Ihnen«). The sentences subject (which stands in nominative) is the interrogative word »was«. »Sie/Ihnen« is not the subject but an object (here an accusative object).

Another step better, but still wrong:

> Was hatten **Ihnen** an Ihrem Heimatland gefallen?

**Fifth error:**
Now the auxiliary verb must be corrected. »Hatten« is wrong, it must be »hat«:

Grammatically correct, but still not a correct translation of your sentence:

> Was **hat** Ihnen an Ihrem Heimatland gefallen?

**sixth error:**
I think this version is among all possible correct sentences the one that is closest to what you did write. But it is in past tense ("What *did* you like about your home country?"). It should be in presence tense:

Now it is good:

> Was gefällt Ihnen an Ihrem Heimatland?

But when talking to a friend or a child you should replace »Sie« by »du«:

> Was gefällt dir an deinem Heimatland?

---

### Fazit

This are good and correct translations:

> Was magst du an deinem Heimatland? (when talking to a friend or a child)
>   Was mögen Sie an Ihrem Heimatland? (when talking to an adult stranger)
>
> Was gefällt dir an deinem Heimatland? (when talking to a friend or a child)
>   Was gefällt Ihnen an Ihrem Heimatland? (when talking to an adult stranger)

Comment: Wow, that's what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: That second sentence came from Google translate btw

Comment: @Ironshot30: Now you can see what bullshit comes out of translation machines. Use it only to translate text from a foreign language into your native language. Then you have good chance to guess what it should have been really. But never use it to translate texts into a language you don't speak.

Answer (score 2):

The German translation of

> What do you like about your home country?

is

> Was mögen Sie an Ihrem Heimatland?

It asks for positive aspects of your country.

---

And the English translation of

> Was halten Sie von Ihrem Heimatland?

is

> What do you think of your home country?

Comment: Thank you, what I am trying to say is: What do you like about your country? Is there a better way to say this?

Comment: Also can you explain the first one why it implies that I love my country when I am asking a question to others if they like their country?

Comment: #1: No, it’s good like this.

Comment: #2: I corrected my answer. I used the wrong word. I meant *like* and not *love*.

Comment: "It implies that you like your country." - no, it does not. It simply asks whether there are any aspects about one's country that one likes. It does not imply anything about whether or not the asked person, in all, likes their country. "Was mögen Sie an ihrem Heimatland?" - "Ich finde mein Heimatland fürchterlich, aber die eine Sache, die mir dort trotzdem gefällt, sind Laugenbrötchen."

Comment: Actually, "Was mögen Sie an Ihrem Heimatland?" does not neccessarily imply that you like your country. It would be perfectly acceptable to reply "Nichts!". You are simply asking for positive aspects while your second suggestion asks for all kinds of properties, both positive and negative.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, Stephie: You’re right. I improved my answer. Thank you.